# Why does the selenium parser not work on a remote machine?

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium + Chrome + python for some activities. On the local machine the script works fine, but I wanted to move it to the server and now the program doesn't work. I suspect very slow internet speed, but maybe the problem is something else. So, my settings:

```
user_agent = FakeUserAgent().chrome
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

The browser starts up fine, but as soon as I try to open any page, it gives the following error:

```
Message: invalid session id
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55c4fd834303 <unknown>
#1 0x55c4fd5190f7 <unknown>
#2 0x55c4fd5569bb <unknown>
#3 0x55c4fd587264 <unknown>
#4 0x55c4fd581ea0 <unknown>
#5 0x55c4fd5816fb <unknown>
#6 0x55c4fd4e5478 <unknown>
#7 0x55c4fd7f86ab <unknown>
#8 0x55c4fd7fc4ba <unknown>
#9 0x55c4fd7e4f85 <unknown>
#10 0x55c4fd7fd12f <unknown>
#11 0x55c4fd7c8e6f <unknown>
#12 0x55c4fd4e382a <unknown>
#13 0x7f18323f7d90 <unknown>
```

Can you tell me what to do about it? I tried pyvirtualdisplay, same thing. I used FireFox browser, but it didn't work at all. Changed option settings - didn't help.

Remote host - Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish, 20 GB memory, 1 GB RAM, CPU(s)
1 Cores
I think the server may lack server capacity, the site is heavy, a lot of JS code.

Thanks)